# The new RefSeq release from NCBI is compatible with Bio.Entrez.Parser?

Tags: python, xml, dtd, biopython, ncbi

I'm new with python and especially with Biopython. I'm trying to take some information from an XML file with `Entrez.efetch` and then read it. Last week this script worked well:

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="Protein", id="YP_008872780.1", retmode="xml")
records = Entrez.read(handle)
```

But now I'm getting an Error:

```
> Bio.Entrez.Parser.ValidationError: Failed to find tag 'GBSeq_xrefs' in
    the DTD. To skip all tags that are not represented in the DTD, please
    call Bio.Entrez.read or Bio.Entrez.parse with validate=False.
```

So I run this:

```
records = Entrez.read(handle, validate=False)
```

But I'm still getting an Error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

After some research I realized that NCBI made [new changes](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mailman/pipermail/refseq-announce/2014q2/000117.html) concerning the `RefSeq` which creates new tags in the xml file (of GenPept)

Do I need to change something in the DTD to support these new tags?

Comment: To display a code you have to first select the text and then click on the {} symbol to mark it as a code snippet. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my DTD file was out of date.
A new version can be found [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/dtd/NCBI_GBSeq.mod.dtd) or [here](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/commit/9a301b5d1cecad1bb2fee3920f73740448f9aa4f).