# socket.gaierror while downloading genbank files w/ biopython

Tags: python, biopython, ncbi, genbank

I would like to download genbank files from NCBI using Biopython and a list of accession numbers (note that I call the script with an email address as an argument e.g., python scriptName.py emailAddress)

```
        import os
        import os.path
        import sys
        from Bio import Entrez
        import datetime
        import time

      ###############################################################################
        # Call Entrez to download files
        # If downloading more than 100 files...
        # Run this script only between 9pm-5am Monday - Friday EST
        # Send E-utilities requests to http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov
        # Make no more than 3 requests every 1 second.
        # Use URL parameter email & tool for distributed software
        # NCBI's Disclaimer and Copyright notice must be evident to users of your service. 
        #
        # Use this script at your own risk. 
        # Neither the script author nor author's employers are responsible for consequences arising from improper usage 
        ###############################################################################
        start_day = datetime.date.today().weekday() # 0 is Monday, 6 is Sunday
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        accession = ['NC_002695.1', 'NC_002128.1', 'NC_002127.1']
        arguments = sys.argv
        Entrez.email = arguments[1]

        if ((start_day < 5 and start_time > datetime.time(hour=21)) or (start_day < 5 and start_time < datetime.time(hour=5)) or start_day > 5 or len(accession) <= 100 ):
            for a in accession:
                print(a)
                if ( (datetime.date.today().weekday() < 5 and datetime.datetime.now().time() > datetime.time(hour=21)) or (datetime.date.today().weekday() < 5 and datetime.datetime.now().time() < datetime.time(hour=5)) or (datetime.date.today().weekday() == start_day + 1 and datetime.datetime.now().time() < datetime.time(hour=5)) or (datetime.date.today().weekday() > 5) or len(accession) <= 100 ):
                    while True:
                        print('Downloading ' + a)
                        #try:
                        handle=Entrez.efetch(db='nucleotide', id=a, rettype='gb', retmode='text') 
                        FILENAME =  'GenbankFiles_E_coli/' + a + '.gb'
                        local_file=open(FILENAME,'w')
                        local_file.write(handle.read())
                        handle.close()
                        local_file.close()
```

When I run the script, it does a partial download of the first file (only) before I get an error:

```
NC_002128.1
Downloading NC_002128.1
Downloading NC_002128.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1182, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 834, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 494, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download_files.py", line 92, in <module>
    handle=Entrez.efetch(db='nucleotide', id=a, rettype='gb', retmode='text') 
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 155, in efetch
    return _open(cgi, variables, post)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 516, in _open
    handle = _urlopen(cgi)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 463, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 481, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1210, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

I have yet to determine if there is an error in my code, if there is an issue with the modules I selected (even though Biopython should handle the calls), if there is an issue with my connection (my job blocks and throttles without warning), or if it is something else.

I have tried running it with and without urllib*/http* modules to no avail (I get the same error). However, the partial file is interesting. Everything up to the final sequences is downloaded (with a contig entry at the end). Here are the last lines of the downloaded file:

```
    /translation="MVPPSAVLCYHNEISRQIPVNMKNIRTEFIPRFNLTLCFPRYWM
TWTGIGIICVFAMVPPALRDPLLGKLGMLVGRLGKSARQRALINLSLCFPEYSDKEKE
NIVDAMFATASMAVVLMAELALSGPDKISHRIRWNGLEIVEKMAQNNEKVIFLVPHAW
GVDIPAMLMAASGRKMAAMFHNQRNPVVDYVWNSVRRRFGGKLHARNDGIASFVRSVR
QGYWGYYLPDQDHGPEFSEFADFFATYKATLPVIGRLSRISGARIIPLFPVYDGKTHH
LTIHVSPPLAIRQKSDAHIARQINEVVENFVRPHPEQYTWILKLLKTRKEGEEDPY"
CONTIG      join(AB011549.2:1..92721) ###this line is not in the original file
//
```

Which can be compared to the original genbank file: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/10955266/?report=genbank

I can confirm that it is not an error related to DTD files but everything else is up for grabs. ([The new RefSeq release from NCBI is compatible with Bio.Entrez.Parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476331/the-new-refseq-release-from-ncbi-is-compatible-with-bio-entrez-parser))

I am running this script on CentOS
Python 3.4.3 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit) :: Biopython 1.66

Comment: What version of Biopython are you using?

Comment: I believe it is biopython-1.65. I can't seem to find a way to do the programName -version for Biopython -- can you suggest something?

Comment: `import Bio; print(Bio.__version__)` will tell you. You might want to upgrade, 1.66 is the latest version. I ran a modified version of your code, and I'm not getting any errors, but the Genbank files don't include the nucleotide sequences shown at nuccore, they end just like your example.

Comment: The output shows that I am using Biopython version 1.66 (thanks for the print trick). Can you please confirm that you were able to download all 3 files and possible share your modified code?

Comment: Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MattDMo/f710d92ef181c05d6073). I only included one `.gb` file, I can add the other two if you want.

Comment: MattdMo -- I really appreciate your efforts on this. I can rule out the code and I believe I am dealing with job-related network restrictions. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The NCBI Entrez fetch API distinguishes return types `rettype="gb"` and `rettype="gbwithparts"`, the first can be shorter by giving you `CONTIG` lines referencing other records, while the later would expand these to give you the full sequence (look for *"GenBank (full)"* in the website).

You can sometimes get a glimpse of this when something is broken on the NCBI side, e.g. http://blastedbio.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/missing-external-exons-in-genbank-with.html and http://blastedbio.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/missing-feature-locations-in-genbank.html (fixed since).

I would guess that the socket error you are getting is related to your work internet access controls.

Comment: access was indeed the problem. Not a pretty solution, but I download the files onto another server (outside of work) and then scp the files over to my work server.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.